# Hadoop:Grouping files for mapping

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I am in the process of developing a program via Hadoop which is relatively new for me, so I would be grateful for an advice on building a conception for what I am planning to do.

I have a large ordered set of 1...n images. Images are logically divided into several groups, each of these groups could be processed independently. However, inside one group all the images are dependent and therefore should be processed by a single Map task. The images themselves are small so loading them into memory simultaneously should be no problem.

I thought of packing each group into a separate SequenceFile, but there seems to be no way to read a SequenceFile from an InputStream...Or, maybe, there is a way to somehow allocate M different nodes for a single MapReduce job so that each node would read its SeqFile directly from the HDFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solving similar problems by encoding images into a string with base64 and then putting them all into an array field of JSON object on preprocess stage.

Furthermore, if you store the JSON into an [AVRO](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/gettingstartedjava.html) format, then you will have a benefit of [out-of-the-box object-oriented interface](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.5/mr.html) to your object in your mapper.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to have a look into `CombineFileInputFormat`, which would help you to group inputs according to a `PathFilter`, say folder wise grouping. And each group can be constructed as a single `Split` which will be processed by a single map task. Since No. of Map tasks = No. of split.

Your needs seems to be similar to [**this link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178033/how-to-process-multiple-folders-in-hadoop/21184210#21184210).Please check.