# How to Process multiple folders in HADOOP

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, hdfs

I'm having the following problem. I have 200k xml files. I have 200 folders and each folder has 2000 xml files. I have this in my HDFS. Architecture is below

```
RootFolder 
   Folder001
       1.xml
       2.xml
       2000.xml
   Folder002
       2001.xml
```

I need to write a mapper program to read the files and do some Xpath process.

If I give the **RootFolder** input path then a mapper should read a folder and process the xml files

That is there should be 200 Task. And each folder should be read by a single mapper

How to process multiple folders?

Comment: each folder should be read by a single mapper ? why are you needing it? it seems uneasy, you describe the job want to complete more specificly , maybe you are asking B but actually want A

Comment: Okay . I need to  extract and write Xpath values in a single file for each folder . So totally there should be 200 output files

Comment: No .. If i create a mapper for each xml then there will be around 2 lak mapper which  will reduce the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you have 2 problems:

1: Need to map all files in a subfolder by a single map task:

Ans: You can make use of `CombineFileInputFormat` for this scenario. It will group files for a specified `PathFilter` (in your case , filter should accept files of same folder) and will assign it to a single maptask. i.e, maptask per folder can be achieved. To get better control please extend `CombineFileInputFormat` and make it your own , that what I do in my case.

2: Need to include files inside the subfolders too as input for your map task(s), by specifying only the root folder.

Ans: In the new API releases, `FileInputFormat` can take files recursively from its subfolders up to any level.
For more info you can see the jira [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193).

Or if you want to do it yourself, subclass `FileInputFormat` and override `listStatus` method.

Comment: It gave me some idea . I don have any sub directories . Can you give me some code example

Comment: Would u mind looking source code of CombineInputFromat [link]( https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java) ? It will give u idea how to input files in each folder to each map task. U better make a subclass of it.